# Trying to code a Python equivalent of SUMIFs feature in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary, data-analysis

I am trying to rewrite a .xlsx file from scratch using Python. The excel sheet has 99 rows and 11 columns. I have generated 99 rows x 8 columns already and I am currently working on generating the 99 rows x 9th column.
This 9th column is calculated based on a SUM-IFS formula in excel. It takes into account columns 2, 4 and 7.

Col. 2 has numerical int values.
Col. 4 has three letter airport code values like NYC for New York City
Col. 7 also has three letter airport code values like DEL for Delhi.

The sum-if formula for column 9 cells 
`SUMIFS(B:B, D:D, D2, G:G, G2)`

Hence it sums the numerical values in column 2 for corresponding cities in col. 4 and col. 7. If there is only one occurrence of the pair of cities in col. 4 and col. 7 then there is nothing to sum and the cell in col.9 = int value of cell in col. 2
However, if are multiple occurrences of the pair of cities in col. 4 and col. 7 then the corresponding values in col. 2 are SUMMED and that becomes the value of the cell in col. 9

Example:

[image]

In this example, col. 2 is Sales, col.4 is Origin City, col. 7 is Destination City and col. 9 is the Result that utilizes `=SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,C2,D:D,D2)`

I am trying to calculate the column 9 using python on the large data set that I have. For now, I have been able to create a list of dictionaries, where I have made the key as origin_city-destination_city and the value as the integer value of col. 2. The list of dicts has 99 rows like the excel file, hence each row of the excel file is represented as a dict. On printing the dictionary, it is something like this:

```
{'YTO-YVR': 570}
{'YVR-YTO': 542}
{'YTO-YYC': 420}
{'YYT-YTO': 32}
{'YWG-YYC': 115}
```

I have been contemplating if it is possible to loop over the list of dicts and create a SUMIFS version of it --- resulting in 99 dicts in the list, with each dict having the sumif value. After this I have to write all these values to the column in the excel file..

I hope someone here can help !! Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas' [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sales': [100,110,200,300,150,200,100],
                   'Origin': ['YYZ','YEA','CDG','YYZ','YEA','YVR','YEA'],
                   'Dest': ['DEL','NYC','YUL','DEL','YTO','HKG','NYC']})

df['Result'] = df.groupby(['Origin','Dest']).Sales.transform('sum')
```

Result:

```
   Sales Origin Dest  Result
0    100    YYZ  DEL     400
1    110    YEA  NYC     210
2    200    CDG  YUL     200
3    300    YYZ  DEL     400
4    150    YEA  YTO     150
5    200    YVR  HKG     200
6    100    YEA  NYC     210
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked for me !! However, I understood df.groupby(['Origin','Dest']) but not '.Sales.transform('sum')' . If you can explain it would be appreciated :)

Comment: `.Sales` is shorthand for `.['Sales']` and means than the following operation (tranform) is applied to this column (Series). `transform` is a bit more difficult to understand - basically it's like an aggregate function (e.g. `.sum()`), but the result is not applied to the groups but to the individual rows, i.e. all rows of a group get the same result assigned. See also for instance [here](https://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html).